# How do I perform Math.round() on an array of double values in Java?

Tags: java

```
public static void formInputParameters(NeuralNetwork loadNet) {
    loadNet.setInput(0.583333333, 0.0, 0.333333333, 0.339622642, 0.251141553, 0.0, 1.0, 0.786259542, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.333333, 0.0);
    loadNet.calculate();
    double[] networkOutput = loadNet.getOutput();
    System.out.println(" Output: " + Arrays.toString(networkOutput));
}
```

How do I perform `Math.round()` on an array of double values in Java?

Comment: please explain what you have tried, what's wrong with that and what's the expected result because it is here very unclear.

Comment: I am working on a neural network and the code about gives this: Output: [0.06118846011827231, 0.8885828608606128, 1.1298737095776684E-10, 6.808363734283252E-9, 3.421583826404654E-4],  I want to be able to round this numbers to [0,1,0,0,0] as my output

Answer (score 1):

Classic way I guess...

```
for (int i = 0; i < networkOutput.lenght; i++) {
    networkOutput[i] = (double) Math.round( (float) networkOutput[i] );
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that [Math.round(double d)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) returns a `long`, not a `double`!

Comment: Actually it can return an integer according to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float). see my edit now.

Comment: The method you're referring to takes a `float` as a parameter, while `networkOutput` is an array of `double`.

Comment: @EnriqueDev I am working on a neural network and the code about gives this: Output: [0.06118846011827231, 0.8885828608606128, 1.1298737095776684E-10, 6.808363734283252E-9, 3.421583826404654E-4], I want to be able to round this numbers to [0,1,0,0,0] as my output. How do I do that?

Comment: Did it work? If it did remember to accept the answer please.